# Como deixar um código HTML/CSS limpo e otimizado?

Tags: html, css

Queria dicas para aplicar no meu aprendizado. Sou um iniciante e sempre escuto falar do código limpo.

Comment: Basta comentar, identar, e organizar bem o código, também mante-los em pastas para não deixar tudo espalhado, evitar ao máximo os famosos POG programação orientada a gambiarra.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link pode te ajudar: https://browserdiet.com/pt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existem regras para um código limpo. Nem nas linguagens de marcação, como é o seu caso, e nem nas de [programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33702/o-que-define-um-c%C3%B3digo-limpo).

### Público alvo do código fonte: trabalho em equipe é *OP*!

É preciso levar em consideração quem lerá o seu código, é importante definir entre a equipe (se houver) convenções, pois existem diversas formas de fazer uma mesma coisa.

**1. Use letras minúsculas nos elementos**. O HTML5 permite a mistura de elementos em letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Você pode usar assim:

```
<DIV> 
  <p>Uma vaga noção de tudo, e um conhecimento de nada. — Charles Dickens</p>
</DIV>
```

ou:

```
<Div> 
  <p>Sábio é aquele que conhece os limites da própria ignorância. — Sócrates</p>
</DIV>
```

ou até:

```
<div> 
  <p>Bom humor. A forma mais simples de superar os problemas. — Rui Barbosa</p>
</div>
```

É recomendado que use o nome dos elementos como no último exemplo, em letras minúsculas, segundo o [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/), pois:

- Misturar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas é ruim.
- Os desenvolvedores normalmente usam em letras minúsculas. (como ocorre no XHTML)
- Letras minúsculas [parecem mais organizados](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml#Capitalization).
- Por fim, a escrita com letras minúsculas são mais fáceis e rápidas de escrever.

**2. Feche todos os elementos.** O HTML5 permite que não precisemos fechar todos os elementos.

```
<section>
  <p>Todos os seus sonhos podem se tornar realidade se você tem coragem para persegui-los. — Walt Disney
</section>
```

No exemplo acima, o elemento `p` foi aberto, porém não foi fechado. Num código mais bonito e organizado (lembrando, você **pode e deve** definir suas próprias convenções com a sua equipe estas apresentadas são dicas, que podem servir como um ponto de partida) seria assim:

```
<section>
  <p>Eu não falhei. Só descobri 10 mil caminhos que não eram o certo. — Thomas Edison</p>
</section>
```

**3. Não economize nos atributos das imagens** O `alt`, por exemplo é importante pois vão existir momentos que por alguma razão a imagem que você definiu não poderá ser exibida, seja por que ela tenha mudado de caminho, ou que ela não exista mais, nestes casos, a sua descrição será exibida.

Já definir a altura e largura da imagem é importante pois o navegador reservará espaço para imagem mesmo antes dela ser carregada, reduzindo o tempo de renderização evitando [*repaints* e *reflows*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549296/whats-the-difference-between-reflow-and-repaint) desnecessários.

Um exemplo ruim de uma imagem seria:

```
<img src="minha-imagem.jpg">
```

Um bom exemplo seria:

```
<img src="minha-imagem.jpg" alt="Descrição da imagem" style="width:128px;height:128px" />
```

**4. A semântica pode deixar o seu código organizado.** Não vou entrar no mérito de explicar a semântica aqui, mas você pode ler clicando [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152265/41056) (vale a pena!). Em resumo, ela divide sua página internamente, sem afetar o visual. Essa divisão deixa seu código mais organizado e segmentado, se quiser mais informações, leia o link que deixei ali em cima.

---

Existem diversos padrões a se estabelecer, inclusive para as folhas de estilo CSS.

As folhas de estilo podem ser curtas, em uma linha só, como esta:

```
p.intro {font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16em;}
```

E elas podem ser escritas de forma longa, como esta:

```
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16em;
  color: black;
}
```

Agora resta a você escolher como você deve definir o padrão, é bom levar alguns parâmetros em consideração: (lembre do início, **não são regras**)

- Linhas muito longas não são legais e podem ser um pouco difícil de manusear, portanto evite.
- A chave de abertura (`{`) pode ser colocada na mesma linha que o *selector*.
- Use aspas somente entre valores que contém espaço.
- Use a chave para fechar o bloco (`}`) na linha logo abaixo do fim do código, evitando espaços.
- Use o ponto e vírgula depois de cada propriedade, até mesmo na última.

Veja o exemplo de um código HTML bonito:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Portfolio | Chris Coyier</title>

    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!--[if gte IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://universal-ie6-css.googlecode.com/files/ie6.0.3.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="home">

    <header>
        <a id="logo" href="/">Site Title</a>
        <div id="slogan">web craftsman, blogger, author, speaker</div>

        <nav>
            <?php include("inc/main-menu.php"); ?>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="container">

        <article>
            <h1>Hipsters</h1>

            <img src="//chriscoyier.net/images/hipster.jpg" alt="Hipster and Company" height="120" width="570" />

            <p>You can&#8217;t dress up as a hipster for Halloween. Their attire is already so bizarre that there isn&#8217;t an
            exaggeration of it that looks like a costume. It would just look like you are another hipster about to read a poem about reading poems.</p>

            <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </article>

        <article>
            <!-- Additional Article -->
        </article>

    </section>

    <aside>
        <h3>My Major Projects</h3>
        <dl>
            <dt><a href="http://aremysitesup.com">Are My Sites Up?</a></dt>
            <dd>Monitor your sites</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a></dt>
            <dd>A web design community</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://digwp.com">Digging Into WordPress</a></dt>
            <dd>Learn about WordPress</dd>
        </dl>
    </aside>

    <footer class="container">
        <h4>People I Enjoy</h4>
        <ul class="col">
            <li><a href="http://fastfoodreviewed.com">Jesse Lynch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://jeffcampana.com">Jeff Campana</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://perishablepress.com">Jeff Starr</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="col">
            <li><a href="http://davidwalsh.name">David Walsh</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://thestrategicretreat.com">Jeff Penman</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://http://shiftedfrequency.com">Richard Felix Jr.</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h4>Sandwiches</h4>
        <ul class="col container" id="sandwich-list">
            <li><a href="http://jimmyjohns.com">Jimmy Johns</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://subway.com">Subway</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://potbelly.com">Potbelly</a></li>
        </ul>

        &copy;2007-<?php echo date("Y"); ?> Chris Coyier
    </footer>

    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
    <script src='/js/main.js'></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics Code -->
    <?php include_once("inc/analytics.php"); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

<sub>Fonte: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CleanCode/Beautiful-HTML.txt)</sub>

Ele é bonito porque segue um **padrão**, do início ao fim, todos os elementos estão sendo fechados, as imagens todas argumentadas, semântico, entre outros fatores.

### Legibilidade e manutenção

[image]

Um código ilegível pode funcionar? Sim.

É o que diz Robert C. Martin em [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) (livro que já foi citado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14275/41056)). A questão é por que não devemos escrever um código ruim? A resposta é **manutenção**.

Recorrendo ao que já foi falado lá em cima, o público alvo do seu código é a sua equipe, e se existe uma equipe, eles também vão prestar manutenção no código que foi escrito.

Um código bem escrito, documentado e legível poupará tempo na manutenção, levando à produtividade.

---

Falar sobre esse assunto é muito delicado pois envolve opinião, já que não existe um guia oficial de HTML/CSS. Tentei deixar o mínimo de argumentação e mais teoria, explicando porque uma coisa é preferível à outra. Deixo para você alguns links que possam ajudar a definir convenções ou até para leitura posterior:

- [Guia de HTML e CSS](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml), do Google
- [Naming Conventions for Class and ID in CSS](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170514), por Molly E. Holzschlag
- [Guia de HTML](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/html/), do Wordpress
- [Mastering the Language of Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073571245X), por Eric Meyer
- [Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14275/41056), por Maniero — foge do ramo HTML/CSS e vai mais para o conceito, também pode te ajudar.
- [O que define um código limpo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33726/41056), por Maniero — mesma coisa do de cima.
- [Como perder peso no browser?](https://browserdiet.com/pt/), por Zeno Rocha e equipe — muitas dicas úteis e mais convenções.
- [Por que não comentar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399158/por-que-n%C3%A3o-comentar-o-c%C3%B3digo), por CypherPotato — explica porque não é ideal usar comentários no código.

Answer (score 1):

- Bem, talvez seja bom começar a aplicar às boas práticas de programação que o
  [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) fornece pois com estas práticas é possível realizar
  manutenções futuramente e serem interpretados por outros programadores.
- Outra prática para o `CSS` é aplicar às Linguagens de Folha de Estilos Dinâmica, existe muitas ferramentas como SASS, [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), STYLUS e dentre outros pois você vai trabalhar com a hierarquia dos elementos e a repetição de códigos, e estas ferramentas tenta minimizar a repetição.
- Por ultimo para otimizar seja bom aprender os Automatizadores de Tarefas como o [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) (Neste caso será necessário aprender sobre [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) nesta etapa), ele traz várias ferramentas que vai diminuir os arquivos sem perder a qualidade, vai verificar os prefixos adequados e organiza-los.