# Como funcionará o operador de atribuição de coalescência nula no PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, operadores

Na versão 7.4 do PHP foi implementado o operador de atribuição de coalescência nula que promete unificar os comportamentos dos operadores de atribuição e de coalescência nula, sendo este último presente desde a versão 7.0.

A ideia é que a linha

```php
$var = $var ?? "default";
```

Possa ser reescrita agora como

```php
$var ??= "default";
```

O que acontecerá nesse caso?

Na [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator) é ainda citado um exemplo um pouco mais complexo:

```php
// The folloving lines are doing the same
$this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] = $this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] ?? 'value';

// Instead of repeating variables with long names, the equal coalesce operator is used
$this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] ??= 'value';
```

O que acontecerá nesse caso? O que incentivou a criação de um novo operador para isso? Apenas para reduzir código escrito? Em que situações esse operador poderá ser realmente útil?

Comment: Eu posso traduzir o que motivou a programadora a criar esse operador. Tá no [github](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1795), mas o texto é curto. Mais interessante são as considerações deles no [StackExchage](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice) porém é muito material para traduzir e colocar em forma de resposta. Por isso lhe pergunto, pois vai demandar tempo e trabalho, essa tradução lhe é interessante e relevante para sua pergunta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Se acha que isso será interessante trazer para cá, fique a vontade :D Entender a motivação sempre é importante

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que acontecerá nesse caso?

É PHP, né? Então já viu, tudo pode acontecer :D Mas se tudo correr bem e eles tomaram decisões corretas (ok, devem ter tomado porque colocaram este caso como exemplo), se o conteúdo de `$this->request->data['comments']['user_id']` for nulo ou indefinido então essa variável (ela completa) passará ter como valor o texto `value`. Note que  é um operador que causa [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101). Até onde eu entendo ele irá criar todos os valores necessários, e o exemplo dá a entender a isso, mas só testando para ter certeza.

> O que incentivou a criação de um novo operador para isso? Apenas para reduzir código escrito?

Acredito que só a simplificação de sintaxe (encurtar código) e linearidade de sintaxe já que outros operadores do tipo permite sua forma composta com a atribuição, e claro que isto pode reduzir a chance de algum erro na hora de fazer a atribuição (é uma forma de [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101)), raro mas pode ocorrer. Não consigo ver outro motivo.

Como é PHP o *pull request* (RFC?!?!?!) e proposta não explica nada conclusivo ou determina a motivação de forma muito forte de algo tão importante que vai mudar na linguagem, parece que era só um desejo e não uma necessidade estudada. Dá a impressão que copiaram de outra linguagem sem considerar as peculiaridades de PHP. *Features* funcionam diferente dependendo de outras *features* que existem na linguagem, tem que ser pensado todos os casos onde será usado e dizer qual é o resultado em todas elas, não é diferente do que fazer qualquer software, só que a relações são mais complexas que a maioria dos softwares.

> Em que situações esse operador poderá ser realmente útil?

Nos mesmos lugares que o `??` era útil e guardava o resultado na própria variável avaliada, o que é a esmagadora maioria dos casos do seus uso. Ele não deverá ser usado se apenas usar o resultado sem guardar em variável, como uma simples impressão, o `return` e qualquer lugar que só exija uma expressão. Lembrando que você só deve guardar em variável aquilo que precisa usar mais de uma vez (existe a questão de fazer isso por legibilidade apenas [em vez de fazer um comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399158/101), mas deve ser usado com parcimônia porque pode até afetar a performance, e neste caso guardará na mesma variável, então não deixará mais legível).

Certeza só quando puder testar e fazer o que eles não fizeram antes de implementar, poderá até achar casos que não forma pensados por eles.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se eu fizer `$var->foo->bar = $var->foo->bar ?? "ok"` funcionará mesmo até quando `$var` não estiver definido e assim define um objeto "recursivamente". Será que o mesmo comportamento se aplicará para esse operador? Se `$var` não existir, define-o, se o campo `foo` não existir, define-o, e, finalmente, se o campo `bar` não existir, define-o?

Comment: Então, é o que eu disse, a proposta é tosca e não fala nada dessas coisas, é como tudo é definido no PHP, é o desejo de alguém, faz e vê o que acontece quando as pessoas começarem usar. Você vê claramente que o processo não observa tudo o que pode ocorrer, não são pessoas que entendem de linguagens de programação que conduzem isto. Eu acho que acontece o que você definiu, ele cria tudo, porque seria consistente, mas vai saber. A maioria das propostas atuais torna tudo inconsistente. Certeza? Só esperando para testar. Pode ser uma surpresa até pra eles.

Comment: Na minha **opinião**, viram isso em C# e resolveram fazer também, só que eles não perceberam que C# não tem variáveis indefinidas. Eles não percebem que cada *feature* que você adiciona na linguagem cria um fardo pra você carregar pro resto da vida. Agora eles querem transformar a linguagem em Java, mas esbarram em todo legado que foi criado para ser uma linguagem de *script*, ou seja, fazer algo rápido e simples, não algo *enterprise*.