# O que é uma documentação formal?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, documentação, comentários

No site do [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp) eles mencionam a expressão "documentação formal".

> It is most common to use single line comments.
>
> Block comments are often used for **formal documentation**.

O que é uma documentação formal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isto está querendo dizer que o comentário será usado para criar documentação.

O **comentário de documentação formal** deve ser público e muitas vezes é usado para criar documentação externa de uma forma mais apresentável para um humano.

Ali terá o nome do objeto, da função, os parâmetros esperados, o retorno, o que eles fazem, que cuidados tomar, eventualmente um exemplo de uso e outros assuntos relacionados. Então esses comentários dão uma base para o programador que for consumir aquilo saber como usar.

Esta documentação mostra os contratos que o consumidor deste objeto/função terão que cumprir para usar de forma correta.

A afirmação do site citado (que é conhecido por ser uma referência ruim e responsável por muita gente aprender errado) dá margem para interpretação. Não está errado porque usa palavras que aceitam outra interpretação mas induz as pessoas a pensar que aquilo ocorra tanto assim, curiosamente os exemplos usados mostram o contrário. O W3Schools mistura conceitos e não fala de fato o que é documentação formal, nem mostra. Ter muitas linhas não tem nada a ver com comentário comum ou de documentação, embora os de documentação sempre terão muitas linhas. Isto é um exemplo de documentação formal:

```
/**
 * Summary. (use period)
 *
 * Description. (use period)
 *
 * @since      x.x.x
 * @deprecated x.x.x Use new_function_name() instead.
 * @access     private
 *
 * @class
 * @augments parent
 * @mixes    mixin
 *
 * @alias    realName
 * @memberof namespace
 *
 * @see  Function/class relied on
 * @link URL
 * @global
 *
 * @fires   eventName
 * @fires   className#eventName
 * @listens event:eventName
 * @listens className~event:eventName
 *
 * @param {type}   var           Description.
 * @param {type}   [var]         Description of optional variable.
 * @param {type}   [var=default] Description of optional variable with default variable.
 * @param {Object} objectVar     Description.
 * @param {type}   objectVar.key Description of a key in the objectVar parameter.
 *
 * @yield {type} Yielded value description.
 *
 * @return {type} Return value description.
 */
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/DocComments.js).

Pode usar uma ferramenta como [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) para ler isto e criar a documentação para você.

Dá para questionar se isso é realmente tão formal assim mas provavelmente eles quiseram dizer que não é um comentário privado, temporário, só para informar os implementadores daquilo.

## Comentário comum

Ele está em oposição ao **comentário comum** que diz algo específico para o código e interno que indica algum problema ou porque foi tomada uma decisão interna. O comentário comum fala sobre o código, ele explica decisões tomadas, é para os autores do código e pessoas que vão ler o código interno. Mesmo comentários comuns não devem dar detalhes do que está fazendo, o código deve ser legível para não precisar disto. Comentários comuns devem ser raros e explicam o porquê de ter feito aquilo e não o que fez.

Alguns comentários comuns ocupam mais de uma linha porque eles explicam o porquê. Mas isto não os torna documentações formais, uma coisa nada tem a ver com a outra.

[Entenda mais sobre comentários comuns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/101). E explicando [porque comentários não deveriam ser usados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399158/101). Os comentários de documentação são sempre bem vindos ao contrário dos comuns.

Comment: só para ver se eu entendi uma documentação formal seria tipo um comentário em que esteja claro para quem está lendo o código?

Comment: @draw Isso que você descreveu é um comentário comum (que independe de ser bloco ou inline). Documentação formal segue um padrão técnico (formal é isso, segue uma forma) para documentar/descrever as propriedades daquele código/biblioteca, e normalmente pode ser lido por ferramentas como [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) e gerar uma documentação separada até. Note o template dado na resposta como exemplo, com `@campos`, e estilo específico.

Comment: Então documentação formal é um comentário que segue uma forma (tipo uma forma de instalar algo no PC passo a passo)?

Comment: Desculpa, é que não ficou muito claro para mim!

Comment: @draw não exatamente, mas se aproxima disso.

Comment: @draw Um comentário formal talvez possa ser comparado ao prefácio de um capítulo, onde se menciona o nome do capítulo, do que ele consiste, coisas muito importantes e/ou relevantes para seu entendimento e talvez uma ou outra informação pra dar contexto a quem está chegando agora. Ele é um "resumo" e costuma trazer bastante informações (normalmente um bloco de comentário) como o exemplo inserido nessa resposta.

Comment: @draw E, apesar de não  haver nenhuma receita de bolo ou padrão que **deve** ser seguido com relação ao layout do comentário formal, dentro de um mesmo projeto todos os blocos de documentação formal tendem a seguir o mesmo padrão, disposição e formatação. Mas isso se deve única e exclusivamente por zelo e organização do programador responsável por escrevê-los.

Comment: 2nmindz, Obrigado pela resposta, acho que entendi um pouco.