# Duvida quanto a semântica do HTML5

Tags: html5

Estou escrevendo uma página tendo em mente cumprir com os padrões semânticos do HTML5. Veja:

```
<section id="experiencia" class="section section-center">
            <header>
                <h2>Experiência</h2>
                <p class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet</p>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <article class="col col-4 block">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Segurança da Informação</h3>
                        </header>
                        <p>Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum. Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,</p>
                        <footer>
                            <p><a href="" class="btn btn-saiba-mais">Saiba mais</a></p>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                    <article class="col col-4 block">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
                        </div>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Webmaster</h3>
                        </header>
                        <p>Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum. Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,</p>
                        <footer>
                            <p><a href="" class="btn btn-saiba-mais">Saiba mais</a></p>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                    <article class="col col-4 block">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-linux"></i>
                        </div>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Sysadmin</h3>
                        </header>
                        <p>Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum. Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,</p>
                        <footer>
                            <p><a href="" class="btn btn-saiba-mais">Saiba mais</a></p>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Conforme pode ser observado, utilizo o **header** logo após a tag **section**, já dentro da tag **article** volto a utilizar **header**. Este emprego estaria correto?

Imagino que o header (cabeçalho) seja relativo a tag que o comporta, seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Seria duplicata? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148753/101

Comment: Relacionado: [Como usar as tais tags semânticas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148753/como-usar-as-tais-tags-sem%C3%A2nticas)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, está correto! A Header estará relativa ao pai, seja ele uma section ou article, vc mostrou exatamente que ela faz parte daquele local. Parabéns!